# How do I boot from USB stick with a new Lenovo laptop and preinstalled Windows 11?

Tags: boot, bios, windows-11, lenovo-laptop, usb-boot

I just bought a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro14IHU5 O with preinstalled Windows 11 Home. I want to boot a different operating system from a USB drive but it just does not work.
When I go to the boot menu (with F12 on startup), the USB stick is not detected.

When I go through the advanced startup menu via the Windows recovery tool, it says at some point "System doesn't have a USB boot option".

Typically it should start by itself once the USB stick is inserted during booting, but it doesn't. What can I do?

What I tried:

- different installations of the boot USB
- disable secure boot in the BIOS/UEFI
- try to activate legacy mode (doesn't exist)
- make sure that "boot from USB" is enabled in the BIOS/UEFI
- disable Intel Secure mode in BIOS (or however it is called) This basically meant I can not start the drive without entering the 48 digit recovery key which is a bit of a pain. It also doesn't allow me to boot from USB.

Comment: Disabled Device Encryption, once you disable it, you will be able to boot multiple operating systems.